# Buffered Writer not writing to txt file from ArrayList

Tags: java

I am having a spot of bother getting BufferedWriter to write output to a txt file I have.

When I compile the program, I do not get any errors but the txt file arrives in my project blank.

I have looked on here at similar questions and tried a few of the proposed solutions to resolve it without success, like closing the stream etc

```
public void storeToDoItemsOntoTxtFile () throws IOException {

    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    BufferedWriter buffyWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);

    try {
        Iterator<ToDoItem> bigIterator = toDoItems.iterator();
        while (bigIterator.hasNext()) {
            ToDoItem item = bigIterator.next();
            buffyWriter.write(String.format("%s\t%S\t%s", item.getShortDescription(), item.getDetails(), item.getDeadline().format(formatter)));
        buffyWriter.newLine();
        }

    } finally {
        if (buffyWriter !=null) {
            buffyWriter.close();// when we are done working with the writer
        }
    }

}
```

> BufferedReader

```
public void loadToDoItemsFromTxtFile() throws IOException {


    toDoItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    BufferedReader buffyReader = Files.newBufferedReader(path); 


    String buffyInput;

    try {

        while ((buffyInput = buffyReader.readLine()) !=null) {

            String [] itemPieces = buffyInput.split("\t");

            String shortDescription = itemPieces[0]; 
            String details = itemPieces[1]; // 
            String dateString = itemPieces [2];

            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
            ToDoItem toDoItem = new ToDoItem(shortDescription,details,date); 
            toDoItems.add(toDoItem);
        }



    } finally {
        if (buffyReader != null) {// ie the buffy reader states that there is a toDoItem" in the txt file
            buffyReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't spot any errors in these methods, so please post the whole program and how you run it.

Comment: Not sure, but I think %S should be lowercase

Comment: Does the `while` loop over `bigIterator` ever get entered?

Comment: I will try all 3 suggestions and post the whole program shortly. appreciate your steering